# Is there a word or phrase that expresses the action of "a person thinking about what another person is doing when the other person is not around"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase that expresses the action of "a person thinking about what another person is doing when the other person is not around". For example, John is sitting in his room in Kentucky, thinking about what his girlfriend was doing in Texas.

Comment: I doubt there is a verb that means all that but there are lots of lovely synonyms for thinking about. How about imagining?

Comment: What Avon said, and "reflecting."

Comment: *pining*? *worrying*? *daydreaming*? Thinking what about his girlfriend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**vicariously** means experiencing through others.

> [vicarious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vicariously?s=t):
>   felt or enjoyed through imagined participation in the experience of others:
>   *a vicarious thrill.*

Comment: meuh - this doesn't really meet the standards of an answer at ELU, it's more of a commentary suggestion. It lacks any supporting references, definitions, links, examples of usage, etc. Add any or all of these things and you will increase the value of this response.

Comment: Thanks! This is along the lines of what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would say he is **preoccupied** (by thoughts of her).

He has a **preoccupation** (with her). Or, she is his preoccupation.

http://i.word.com/idictionary/preoccupied

http://i.word.com/idictionary/preoccupation

"Obsessed/obsession" are used similarly, but they sound a bit stronger than what you described.